# TzInfo error when unsing Func() on a DatetimeField

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model A:

```
class A(models.Model):
   start_datetime = models.DatetimeField()
   end_datetime = models.DatetimeField()
   status = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

And I'm trying to count the number of "row" group by "day".

So here is my query:

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(status='OK')
queryset = queryset.annotate(day=Func(F('start_datetime'), function='DATE'))
queryset = queryset.values('day')
queryset = queryset.annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

And when I try to print the queryset: `print(queryset)`

I got this error message:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

I understand **why** but I don't **how to solve this**.

In my settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montreal'
USE_TZ = True
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution which is this one:

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(status='OK')
queryset = queryset.annotate(day=Trunc('start_datetime', 'day', output_field=DateField()))
queryset = queryset.values('day')
queryset = queryset.annotate(total=Count('id'))
queryset = queryset.order_by('-day')
```

It works as expected.